# Showing Spans are the same

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two sets of vectors $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ each consisting of $m$ vectors in $\Re^N$, $m\leq N$.

I want to show that their spans are the same i.e.$$span(\mathcal{A})=span(\mathcal{B})$$

I showed it by inclusion i.e. by showing for all $x\in span(\mathcal{A})$, $x\in span(\mathcal{B})$ and the other way around.

A friend of mine showed that for all $x\in\mathcal{A}$, $x\in span(\mathcal{B})$ and the other way around. I feel this is not enough but I can't come up with a counter example.

Can anyone help me by showing that they are either equivalent or give me a counterexample?

Comment: If $y\in\text{span}\, \mathcal A$, then $y$ is a linear combination of elements from $\mathcal A$. Hence $y\in\text{span}\,\mathcal B$ if each member of $\mathcal A$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient.

Show that for all $x\in A$, $x\in span (B) \Leftrightarrow span A \subset span B$.

Comment: I see! Thank You! I will accept answer as soon as system allows. Also, Does it matter whether we are working in $\Re^n$ or not? What if the space was infinite dimensional or some other oddity was present?

Comment: @FightCllub What do you think?

Comment: There has to be a case when something goes wrong. The way I think about it, we are checking if the "basis vectors" of one subspace can be expressed as a linear combination in the other. But, I feel there must be a case when this is not sufficient.

Comment: Remember that the span is defined as "finite linear combinations".

Comment: I see. So, this must hold irrespective of the metric space.

Comment: @FightCllub when working with infinite dimensional spaces, an equivalent result holds for subspaces generated by sets A and B.